# Politics of change of credentials on Heroku-Postgres

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I had my application configured and deployed with a database that already had some records, today without knowing why the credentials have changed and with it the access to the database.

I would like to know under what parameters and how often Heroku does this kind of thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a question for Heroku's support team rather than a question for SO.

Comment: Sorry, heroku redirects me here to support their free services.